# Quoted string not properly terminated in SQL

Tags: sql

I know that I have to look for a quotation that I did not close, but I can't seem to find that. Is something else causing this?

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employee(EmployeeID, SSN, LastName, FirstName, Title, Salary,   
     2  ParkingSpace, DepartmentNumber)

     3  VALUES ('12345', '123456789', 'Smithxxxxxxx', 'Aerij', 'Boss', '6000.95', '54321', '6754');
```

> ERROR: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: I'm assuming those numbers at the start of the lines weren't part of the original SQL command?

Comment: Could you show us your table schema?

Comment: This is the table if it helps? https://pastebin.com/1gDzzHFt